# Como integrar DataTables con este tipo de respuesta Json

Tags: json

Tengo un problema para integrar Data tables con el json que recibo de respuesta por parte de mi servidor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código que estoy manejando es este:

```
function lstCiudades(){
$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"php/catalogo/class.Ciudades.php",
    data: "func=lst"
}).done(function (res){
    var resp = eval("("+res+")");
    if (resp["status"] == "ok_lst"){
      $('#tbbTable').DataTable({
          "ajax": resp["success"]
      });
      //imp(resp);
    }else if (resp["status"] == "warning_lst") {
        Toast.fire({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Ocurrió una alerta',
          text: resp["warning"]["message"],
        }); 
    }else{
        Toast.fire({
          type: 'warning',
          title: 'Ocurrió un error inesperado:',
          text: 'Reinicie el sitio web.',
        }); 
    }
});     
}
```

Necesito saber como estructurar el contenido en esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner como exactamente te pone el JSON haz un console.log(res)